# Can not run node server file on Ubuntu server

Tags: node.js, ubuntu

i am unable to start my `server.js` file on Ubuntu server.I installed all npm packages successfully.But when i run command `node server.js` The script is not executing at all and there is no error also. After hit enter it is again move back to the folder path in putty ssh.I am explaining my code below.

> server.js:

```
var port=8888;
var express=require('express');
var morgan = require('morgan');
var http=require('http');
var bodyParser= require('body-parser');
var methodOverride = require('method-override');
var mongo = require('mongojs');
var database='Oditek';
var collections=['video'];
var app= express();
var server=http.Server(app);
var io=require('socket.io')(server);
var db = mongo.connect("127.0.0.1:27017/"+database, collections);
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));     // set the static files location /public/img will be /img for users
app.use(morgan('dev'));                     // log every request to the console
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))    // parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.json())    // parse application/json
app.use(methodOverride());                  // simulate DELETE and PUT
db.on('ready', function () {
    console.log('database connected')
});
app.get('/',function(req,res){
    res.sendfile('view/login.html');
});
app.post('/login',function(req,res){
    var username=req.body.username;
    var password=req.body.userpassword;
    if(username && password){
        db.video.findOne({
            username:username,
            password:password
        },function(err,doc){
            if(doc){
                console.log('login',doc);
                res.send(doc);
            }
            if(err){
                console.log('login12',err);
                res.send("could not login");
            }
        });
    }
});
app.get('/index',function(req,res){
    res.sendfile('view/index.html');
});
app.get('/video',function(req,res){
    res.sendfile('view/video.html');
});
app.get('/whiteboard',function(req,res){
    res.sendfile('view/whiteboard.html');
});
//socket----programming//
var roomid;
var clients={};
io.on('connection',function(socket){
    //console.log('socket id',socket);
    if(socket.handshake.query.roomid){
      roomid=socket.handshake.query.roomid;
    }
    var usertype=socket.handshake.query.usertype;
    //var url=socket.handshake.headers.referer;
    //var myString = url.substr(url.indexOf("?") + 1);
    //var usertype=myString.substr(myString.indexOf("=")+1);
    //console.log('usertype',usertype);
    clients[usertype]={
        "socket":socket.id
    }
    console.log('clients',clients['admin'].socket);
    socket.on('admin-join',function(data){
        if(data.IsJoinAdmin){
            socket.join(roomid);
        }
    });
    socket.on('user-join',function(data){
        console.log('user wants to join',data);
        //console.log('user type',clients);
        if(data.isUserJoin){
            io.sockets.connected[clients[data.usertype].socket].emit('user-already-joined',data);
            socket.join(roomid);
        }
    });
    socket.on('send-playing-video-request-to-users',function(data){
        io.to(roomid).emit('sending-broadcasting',data);
    });
    socket.on('send-broadcasting-message',function(data){
        io.to(roomid).emit('sending-broadcasting',data);
    });
    socket.on('share-white-board',function(msg){
        io.to(roomid).emit('sharing-white-board',msg);
    });
    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
    for(var user in clients) {
        if(clients[user].socket === socket.id) {
            delete clients[user];
            io.to(roomid).emit('user-has-left',{userleft:true});
            break;
        }
    }   
  })

});
server.listen(port);
console.log('server is listening on the port'+port);
```

at least the console message should execute if this file is running.But i am not getting like that.Please help me to resolve this error.

Comment: Can you try `node --version` and `sudo node server.js` and tell us your results?

Comment: @trex005 : After typing the two command same result coming i.e.move back to the directory path.No result showing.

Comment: something is wrong with your node, or you have something else called node installed as well.  can you run the command `which node`?

Comment: @trex005:it is giving me the output as `/usr/sbin/node`.

Comment: How about `dpkg -l | grep node`

Comment: @trex005: i could not understand.Shall i run above command ? actually i am using first time node in ubuntu.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85100/discussion-between-trex005-and-satya).

Answer (score 0):

There is another program called `node` which would show no output when called named "Amateur Packet Ratio Node program".  From chatting with you, I have determined that this is what is on your system.  There are two basic solutions.

1. Remove "Armature Packet Ratio Node program", and reinstall node.js

.

```
sudo apt-get purge node nodejs  # Uninstall both
sudo apt-get install nodejs  # Reinstall nodejs
```

2. Living with both programs and accessing node.js through node.js

.

```
nodejs server.js
forever -c 'nodejs server.js' start
```